# CAML Query: filter items between dates

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, caml-query

How to filter items between two dates with camel query?

For example, I want to retrieve items created between `2019-9-1` and `2019-10-5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date and time in sharepoint is ISO 8601 format. You could try the below script:

```
$spweb = get-spweb http://sp/sites/test/ 
$splist = $spweb.Lists.TryGetList("TestList")
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.Query = 
   "   <Where>
      <And>
         <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='Created' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'>2019-09-01T12:00:00Z</Value>
         </Geq>
         <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name='Created' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'>2019-10-05T12:00:00Z</Value>
         </Leq>
      </And>
   </Where>"; 
$items = $splist.GetItems($query)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like below:

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <And>
      <Geq>
        <FieldRef Name="Created" />
        <Value IncludeTimeValue="FALSE" Type="DateTime">2019-09-01</Value>
      </Geq>
      <Leq>
        <FieldRef Name="Created" />
        <Value IncludeTimeValue="FALSE" Type="DateTime">2019-10-5</Value>
      </Leq>
    </And>
  </Where>
</Query>
```