# How to filter items with a date range using query parameters of Render list data as stream rest api?

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, filter, date-time

Microsoft Documentation is providing filter operator which takes greater than, less than or equal to but it is working?

[RenderListDataAsStream URI parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest#renderlistdataasstream-uri-parameters)

The documentation says we can use filterOP, filterField, filterValue that can be used for filtering, so I have used `filterField1=created&filterValue1={startDate}&filterOp1=Geq&filterField2=created&filterValue2={endDate}&filterOp1=Leq` to get the items created between start date and end date but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter list items using CAML query when fetching list items using `RenderListDataAsStream` endpoint.

You can pass the CAML query to POST API like below example:

```
POST: https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site-name>/_api/web/Lists(guid'<list-guid>')/RenderListDataAsStream

Body: {
  "parameters": {
    "RenderOptions": 2, // ListData
    "ViewXml": "<View>
                  <ViewFields>
                    <FieldRef Name=\"ValoNavigation\"/>
                  </ViewFields>
                  <Query>
                    <Where>
                      <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name=\"ID\"/>
                        <Value Type=\"Number\">1</Value>
                      </Eq>
                    </Where>
                  </Query>
                  <RowLimit Paged=\"TRUE\">1</RowLimit>
                </View>"
  }
}
```

**Source**: [Using the SharePoint RenderListDataAsStream API to fetch lookup and single managed metadata field values](https://www.eliostruyf.com/using-sharepoint-renderlistdataasstream-api-fetch-lookup-single-managed-metadata-field-values/)

You can find more information about CAML query schema at: [Query Schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/query-schema)

---

For date range CAML query examples, check below links:

1. [CAML Query: filter items between dates](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/270560/caml-query-filter-items-between-dates)
2. [CAML Query filtering data within a date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873761/caml-query-filtering-data-within-a-date-range)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question @Ganesh, But I need to use only query parameters

Comment: I haven't tried using query parameters. But the "Marc Anderson" also mentioned in one of [his blog](https://sympmarc.com/2018/03/22/enable-support-for-lookup-columns-in-other-webs-in-the-rest-api-boom-its-done/): "*I also can’t get filters to work using the FilterOp1-10 parameters, nor do several other of the parameters do what I would expect, and I can’t find ANY examples (other than the ones in the documentation page, which really don’t cover anything useful) showing how to use this endpoint.*". So if you want you can try using CAML query & see if it works for you!

Comment: But why did Microsoft documentation "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest" mentioned the filter op operator

Answer (score 0):

REST API with date range parameters works for me in SPO/SPFx. Just make sure date range is formatted correctly. Here is an example:

```
https://MysharePoint.tenant.com/sites/siteColl/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('myLibrary')/items?$top=5000&$Select=ID, Title, AssignedTo/Title, AssignedTo/EMail, Modified,Created&$Expand=AssignedTo/Id&$filter=(created%20ge%20datetime'2021-5-23T00:00:00' and created%20le%20datetime'2021-5-24T00:00:00')
```

Comment: OP specifically asked for `RenderListDataAsStream` endpoint API.